# write items from a list to csv file column by column using pandas dataframe.to_csv

Tags: csv, pandas

I have a list named items
`items=['a' , 'b','c']`
Code is:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(items)
df.to_csv("myfile.csv",headers=None,index=False)
```

the values written to the file are in different rows but same column.(vertically written)
But
I want the values to be written as : `a b c` ie. in same row but different column.
Help please

Answer (score 2):

You get each element in different rows because you load the df as that way.

If you want in different column I would suggest to do transpose,

```
df = df.T
```

or you can load as one row like below,

```
items=[['a' , 'b','c']]
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
df
Out[22]: 
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
```

And then write the output to csv,

eg:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(items)
df = df.T
df.to_csv("myfile.csv",headers=None,index=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(items)

df
Out[5]: 
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c

df.T
Out[11]: 
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
```